# Angular.js group by sub property

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, loops

I have such JSON file:

```
{
"dates": 
[
    {
    "day": "Monday",
    "shifts": [
        {
            "shift-name": "shift 1",
            "assignments": [
                {
                    "position-name": "supervisor",
                    "location-name": "Location 2", 
                    "persons": [
                        {
                            "person-name": "USI, ANTHONY RN"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "position-name": "driver(s?)",
                    "location-name": "LOCATION 1",
                    "persons": [
                        {
                            "person-name": "LOVELAND, VIVIENNEW"
                        },
                        {
                            "person-name": "LOVELAND, VIVIENNEW"
                        }
                    ]
                }...
```

And I need to create a loop using this JSON. But I need to make it in a way that all persons are grouping by location-name. But I don't know how to do it as location name could be duplicated. So the structure should be like this:

```
Date
  Location1
     Shift1
       Supervisors
       Drivers
     Shift2
       Supervisors
       Drivers
  Location2
     Shift1
       Supervisors
       Drivers
     Shift2
       Supervisors
       Drivers
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example I take abstract test.json file with your structure. And get the data form XmlHttpRequest:

```
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", 'test.json', true);
    xhr.onload = function(){
        // get result
        var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        // result
        var result = {};
        // go loop!
        data.dates.forEach(function(day){
            // check if day exists
            result[day.day] = result[day.day] || {};
            day.shifts.forEach(function(shift){
                shift.assignments.forEach(function(assignment){
                    //check if location exists
                    result[day.day][assignment['location-name']] = result[day.day][assignment['location-name']] || {};
                    // ... if shift exists in this location
                    result[day.day][assignment['location-name']][shift['shift-name']] = result[day.day][assignment['location-name']][shift['shift-name']] || {};
                    // ... if position-name exists in this location -> shift
                    result[day.day][assignment['location-name']][shift['shift-name']][assignment['position-name']] = result[day.day][assignment['location-name']][shift['shift-name']][assignment['position-name']] || [];
                    // ... push persions in position-name array
                    assignment.persons.forEach(function(person){
                        result[day.day][assignment['location-name']][shift['shift-name']][assignment['position-name']].push(person);
                    })
                });
            });
        });
        // print result
        console.log(result)
    };
    xhr.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to map this data to a new flatter structure that represents what you want to use it for

Generally the best way to approach something like this is to create a temporary object that uses the common value as keys. Then push items to array(s) based on those keys.

So first you would iterate `dates`.

Within each iteration of dates create an empty object.

Then you would loop over `assignments` creating object keys using `location-name` values as keys.

That object would look something like:

```
{
   "Location 1":{"supervisors":[], "drivers":[]},   
   "Location 2":{"supervisors":[], "drivers":[]}
}
```

Then as you iterate over `persons` you use `"position-name"` to determine which array to push to. That step would look something like:

Finally you iterate that object to create the arrays needed for locations for that date and the dates loop continues and repeats process in next iteration